# scroll div with uncertain height

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a situation where I have a want to scroll the main content div but not the header. My header has a fixed height, and the content div is meant to stretch the rest of the vertical space, with a scroll bar if the content stretches beyond the bottom of the page. Normally I would use absolute positioning on the content div (`top:height-of-header, bottom:0, left:0, right:0`), and set `overflow-x` to `auto`. However, it's complicated by the fact that I have an additional div between the header and content which has a flexible height based on its contents and only sometimes appears (I have a button that toggles visibility of that div). As such, I can't use absolute positioning for the content div because the top distance varies. I also can't use percentage heights because I want the non scrolling portions to be the just-right height for their content, rather than based on a percentage of the page.

Here's a simplified version of the setup:

```
<div id="header"></div>     <--- Fixed height
<div id="adddiv"></div>     <--- Not always visible. Flexible height.
<div id="content"></div>    <--- The only one I want scrolling
```

Edit: Added a jsfiddle with a larger example here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/r7b30v2f/4/
(without the scrollbar working the way I want)

Since I'm already using javascript to handle the toggling of the "middle" div, I could always use javascript to change the top value for the content div depending on whether or not the middle div is displaying. But I would prefer a css solution if there is one.

Comment: Please post your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It will only place the scroll bar in the contents div if the contents div height or max-height is set. CSS Example:

```
#contents {
    max-height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

EDIT: You could try setting the height by figuring out the height of the header + the height of the adddiv.

```
var headerHeight = document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;
var adddivHeight = document.getElementById("adddiv").offsetHeight;
var heightUsed = headerHeight + adddivHeight;
var totalHeight = screen.height;
var height = totalHeight - heightUsed;
```

(I did try something like this but I couldn't get it to work, I just thought I'd share what I think could be the solution.)

Comment: max-height won't work for me here because I need it to be responsive for different devices - desktop, tablet, mobile, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably end up falling back to a javascript solution like this (which will need to be hooked up to the page resize event) if I can't find a css solution. I'd prefer a css solution if there is one though.